# How to connect to mssql from php?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a dedicated centos server.  It needs to be able to connect to a remote windows machine running SQL Server 2012.  The provider installed freetds.  I'm running PHP Version 5.3.28.

We can ping the remote ms-sql server from the linux box.  But, when I try to run the test command: tsql -S your.server.name -p 1433  -U  -P   it times out.

I tried the sample code I found online to test via php, but as my version is greater than 5.3 the mssql_connect function no longer is functional.

```
$conn = mssql_connect("servername", "<user>", "<password>");
```

I get 
    Call to undefined function mssql_connect()...so, I'll have to use PDO (I think).

Anyway, the PDO probably won't work until we get the tsql to work, and it just times out.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have always had to resort to Java and the JDBC driver for SQL Server when connecting from Linux to SQL Server.  I am interested in the answers here.  The only thing I could find were commercial drivers that my company was not willing to pay for.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few comments in the mssql_connect section of the php manual. Various people having had similar problems with connecting from linux/unix.

Maybe there is some insight there: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Also, as always, make sure you have physical connectivity from the box itsself and from within php.

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure that nothing block the port 1433.

Try to run  thd command:

telnet yourserver.com 1433

If you get enter - try to check configuration of the driver and configuration of mssql server.